# Move webpack babel loader configuration to .babelrc

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I have the following webpack loader configuration that works great, but I want to move the babel options to a `.babelrc` file. When I cut/paste (and update the syntax) into the `.babelrc` file, it no longer transpiles the code and throws errors that it can find loaders. The rc file is in root, and if I remove the plugins the alias fails so I'm confident it's finding the file. Using webpack 4 and babel-loader 8.

Webpack (which works):

```
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', {
                'corejs': '3.35',
                'useBuiltIns': 'entry'
              }]
            ],
            plugins: [
              ['babel-plugin-module-resolver', {
                'alias': {
                  '~': './src'
                }
              }],
              '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind'
            ],
            comments: false
          }
        },
        exclude: {
          and: [/node_modules/],
          not: [
            /ol/,
          ]
        }
      },
```

.babelrc (doesn't work)

```
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "corejs": "3.35",
      "useBuiltIns": "entry"
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "~": "./src"
      }
    }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind"
  ],
  "comments": false
}
```

Comment: Instead of _.babelrc_ name the file _babel.config.json_

Comment: That worked, thanks. Is Babel{-loader} just buggy, or is there a reason why that name is perferred?